# Creating a property selector Expression from a string

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, lambda

I'm trying to generate a "Property Selector" from a string.

Let me explain myself a bit with a Real life example:

**We have a Person class with a Name (string) property.**

I could manually create a "property selector" like this propertySelector writing:

```
Expression<Func<Person, string>> propertySelector = x => x.Name;
```

But I would like to get the same property selector with my method.

```
var propertySelector = CreatePropertySelectorExpression<Person, string>("Name");
```

What I have so far is this:

```
public static Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>> CreatePropertySelectorExpression<TIn, TOut>(string path)
{
    Expression exp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TIn), "x");
    foreach (var property in path.Split('.'))
    {
        exp = Expression.PropertyOrField(exp, property);
    }
    return exp;
}
```

But... I've got and invalid cast error!

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression' to
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I'm very new to Expressions and I don't know how to continue :(

Comment: please could you add a real example of use?

Comment: There are some error in your code, for example Expression.Parameter will return ParameterExpression, Expression.PropertyOrField will return MemberExpression, sincerely I don't understand what would you achieve

Comment: Please, check the edit I've just made. I put a much better example. Maybe the code is wrong. I'm a newbie regarding Expressions :( Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your `exp` only contains the body of the lambda. But you want an actual lambda function that takes a parameter of type `TIn` there. So you need to create a lambda using `Expression.Lambda`:

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TIn));
var body = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, propertyName);
return Expression.Lambda<Func<TIn, TOut>>(body, param);
```

Note though that the expression does not really help you much. You probably want a compiled function instead:

```
private static Func<TIn, TOut> CreatePropertyAccessor<TIn, TOut> (string propertyName)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TIn));
    var body = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, propertyName);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TIn, TOut>>(body, param).Compile();
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
var name1 = CreatePropertyAccessor<Obj, string>("Name");
var name2 = CreatePropertyAccessor<Obj, string>("Name2");
var name3 = CreatePropertyAccessor<Obj, string>("Name3");

var o = new Obj() // Obj is a type with those three properties
{
    Name = "foo",
    Name2 = "bar",
    Name3 = "baz"
};

Console.WriteLine(name1(o)); // "foo"
Console.WriteLine(name2(o)); // "bar"
Console.WriteLine(name3(o)); // "baz"
```

Comment: Do you know that how to pass <Tout> dynamiclyaccording to given Type of Obj.