Adding a where to a generic expression in a custom Entity Framework Core .Include
We have a custom static class containing a custom .Include method to be used when using Entity Framework Core to call a repository. We would like the include to take whatever selector has been provided, for example i.Documents as shown here:
private readonly IRepository<Item> _itemRepository;

var item = await _itemRepository.GetAll()
                                .IncludeCheckingSecurity(i => i.Documents)
                                .SingleAsync();

And if the repository is of a certain type (IObjectWithSecurity) and the selector is of a certain type (IEnumerable of IObjectWithSecurity) to add an additional .Where() for the selector filtering on a property that exists on IObjectWithSecurity:
public static IIncludableQueryable<TRepositoryType, TThisInclude> IncludeCheckingSecurity<TRepositoryType, TThisInclude>(
this IQueryable<TRepositoryType> source,
Expression<Func<TRepositoryType, TThisInclude>> propertySelector)
where TRepositoryType : class
{
   var previousType = typeof(TRepositoryType);
   var thisInclude = typeof(TThisInclude);

   if (typeof(IObjectWithSecurity).IsAssignableFrom(previousType) && typeof(IEnumerable<IObjectWithSecurity>).IsAssignableFrom(thisInclude))
   {
       // Want to add a where to 'propertySelector' which filters it on a property within IObjectWithSecurity (which we have proved it is above)
       return source.Include(propertySelector);
   }
}

EDIT
For example, this call to the repository:
private readonly IRepository<Item> _itemRepository;

var item = await _itemRepository.GetAll()
                            .IncludeCheckingSecurity(i => i.Documents)
                            .SingleAsync();

Should actually result in this:
private readonly IRepository<Item> _itemRepository;

var item = await _itemRepository.GetAll()
                            .IncludeCheckingSecurity(i => i.Documents.Where(a => a.AllowAccess))
                            .SingleAsync();

Where i.Documents is an Enumerable of a type that inherits from IObjectWithSecurity. And AllowAccess is a property on IObjectWithSecurity:
public interface IObjectWithSecurity 
{
    public bool AllowAccess { get; set; }
}

We have experimented with creating additional expressions and using lambda to join them:
Expression<Func<TThisInclude, bool>> whereToAppend = e => ((IObjectWithSecurity)e).AllowAccess;
var newIncludeWithWhere = Expression.Lambda<Func<TRepositoryType, TThisInclude>>(Expression.AndAlso(propertySelector, whereToAppend), propertySelector.Parameters);
return source.Include(newIncludeWithWhere);

But without success as it seems this is more designed for joining 2 where expressions instead of a member access expression and a where expression on its collection.

Too abstract question. Everything is possible, but which expression you expect after transformation? I cannot handle it from original question.

There's a repository class that has this all nicely implemented: DbSet. It always strikes me as a bit weird that so many people bury EF DbSets in a repository and then jump through hoops and loops to dig all kinds of tunnels to it. All under the guise of abstraction, which is immediately broken by EF-specific methods like this.

I believe that this might point you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669993/creating-a-property-selector-expression-from-a-string

@SvyatoslavDanyliv - the return of the whole static method will be IIncludableQueryable<TRepositoryType, TThisInclude>. propertySelector should end up as Expression<Func<TRepositoryType, TThisInclude>>. We want to take a memberaccess expression that is inputted (propertySelector) and add a where clause to it. However it will be a generic type and will need casting to IObjectWithSecurity if it is indeed assignable. There is then a boolean on IObjectWithSecurity which we want to verify is true. Hope this helps

@sjones, update question with non-dynamic example. Like, if I put these parameters, this expression should be generated.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv - done, please see edit, thanks

@sjones Include is already generic. Generic means you can use strongly typing at compile time without modifying the method, in this case Include<TEntity>. Your actual question is what to do when you de-genericize it by wrapping a CRUD class over the Unit-of-Work that is DbContext, which now forces you to construct at runtime the expression you could already provide. That's a problem of the pseudo-repository antipattern, not Include

As for filtering, the appropriate feature is global query filters, not filtering on Include. You may forget that Where, while the filter is always there. For actual security you have to use database permissions. You can easily map to views that have SELECT permissions only for specific roles or accounts. Nothing can bypass those permissions, no matter how the connection is made

This extension enables adding an additional security filter to the Include expression:
public static class SecurityExtensions
{
    public static IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, IEnumerable<TProperty>> IncludeCheckingSecurity<TEntity, TProperty>(this IQueryable<TEntity> query, Expression<Func<TEntity, IEnumerable<TProperty>>> property) 
        where TProperty : IObjectWithSecurity 
        where TEntity : class
    {
        // Define a template filter expression to apply access checking
        Expression<Func<IEnumerable<TProperty>, IEnumerable<TProperty>>> filterTemplate = p => p.Where(x => x.AllowAccess);

        // Replace parameters in the template with those from the property expression
        var newIncludeBody = ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(filterTemplate.Parameters[0], property.Body, filterTemplate.Body);

        // Create a new lambda expression using the modified include body
        var newIncludeLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, IEnumerable<TProperty>>>(newIncludeBody, property.Parameters);

        // Apply the modified include expression with security filtering
        return query.Include(newIncludeLambda);
    }
}


This is excellent, exactly what I was after! Thank you Svyatoslav for your patience and answer, all the best
